# How to use map function with a number state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops

I want to use map function with a number state. You guys already know that the map function works with arrays. But I want to use it with a number, not an array. Because I dont't want to create an array to use map function. And For loop is not works wll in jsx. So let's go to codes.

I'm defining the number state that I'm in a trouble:

```
const [pages, setPages] = useState(5)
```

Now, it's time to use map function. It's working with just a number:

```
[...Array(5)].map((page,i) => 
    <div>Page: {i+1}</div>
)
```

But it's not working with my number state that I defined before:

```
[...Array(pages)].map((page,i) => 
    <div>Page: {i+1}</div>
)
```

This is actually my biggest problem with the map function.

Comment: What's "not working" about it?  In what specific way does the code fail?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] to demonstrate?

Comment: @David I found the problem. It's actually working with another state. The reason that it's not working with the pages state is there was a function which sets the state to different number. And when I get the function under comment line it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work fine. Here is the live demo for the reference. Kindly check and try to find the root cause.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const {useState} = React;

function Example() {
    
    const [pages, setPages] = useState(5);
    
    return (
        <div>
          <div>{[...Array(pages)].map((page,i) =>
            <div>Page: {i+1}</div>
          )}
          </div>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```